# How is the ANSI C function declaration an improvement on the old Kernigan and Ritchie style?

Tags: c

With regards to the ANSI C function declaration, how is this an improvement from the old K&R style? I know the differences between them, I just want to know what problems could arise from using the old style and how the new style is an improvement.

Comment: I see there's a vote to close this. I agree the question is potentially vague, but I believe there is a concrete answer (see mine).

Answer (score 8):

Old-style function *declarations*, in particular, don't allow for compile-time checking of calls.

For example:

```
int func(x, y)
char *x;
double y;
{
     /* ... */
}
```

...

```
func(10, 20);
```

When the compiler sees the call, it doesn't know the types of the parameters of the function `func`, so it can't diagnose the error.

By contrast:

```
int better_func(char *x, double y) {
    /* ... */
}
```

...

```
better_func(10, 20);
```

will result in a compiler error message (or at least a warning).

Another improvement: prototypes make it possible to have functions with parameters of type `float`, and of integer types narrower than `int` (the 3 `char` types and the two `short` types). Without a prototype, `float` is promoted to `double`, and narrow integer types are promoted to `int` or to `unsigned int`. With a prototype, a `float` argument is passed as a `float` (unless the function is variadic, like `printf`, in which case the old rules apply to the variadic arguments).

The [C Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) document discusses this in section 6.7.5.3, probably better than I have:

> The function prototype mechanism is one of the most useful additions 
>   to the C language. The feature, of course, has precedent in many of
>   the Algol-derived languages of the past 25 years.  The particular form
>   adopted in the Standard is based in large part upon C++.
>
> Function prototypes provide a powerful translation-time error 
>   detection capability. In traditional C practice without prototypes, it
>   is extremely difficult for the translator to detect errors (wrong
>   number or type of arguments) in calls to functions declared in another
>   source file.  Detection of such errors has occurred either at runtime
>   or through the use of auxiliary software tools.
>
> In function calls not in the scope of a function prototype, integer
>   arguments have the *integer promotions* applied and **float**
>   arguments are widened to **double**. It is not possible in such a call
>   to pass an unconverted **char** or **float** argument. Function
>   prototypes give the programmer explicit control over the function
>   argument type conversions, so that the often inappropriate and
>   sometimes inefficient default widening rules for arguments can be
>   suppressed by the implementation.

There's more; go read it.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the K&R style is much more consistent with the basic idea of C declarations; "declaration mimics use".

Comment: Why can't the compiler detect the type mismatch with the K&R-style function?  All the type information is still present.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Not necessarily. An old-style non-prototype function *declaration* doesn't include the body of the function, so it doesn't provide parameter type information. Example: `int func();` in `some_header.h`. The full *definition* does provide that information but (a) it's likely not to be in the same source file, and (b) the compiler isn't required to make use of it even if it is. Calling a non-prototyped function with invalid arguments has undefined behavior; it needn't be diagnosed.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm not sure how they could have considered my question as vague because you have answered it for me perfectly, thanks again :)

Comment: @RichardGray: Questions of the form "Why is X better than Y" can often "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". I think your question is an exception to that.

Answer (score 3):

A non-defining function *declaration* in K&R looks as follows

```
int foo();
```

and introduces a function that accepts *unspecified* number of arguments. The problem with such declaration style is obvious: it specifies neither the number of parameters nor their types. There's no way for the compiler to check the correctness of the call with respect to the number of arguments or their types at the point of the call. There's no way for the compiler to perform the argument type conversion or issue and error message in situations when argument type does not match the expected parameter type.

A function declaration, which is used as a part of function *definition* in K&R looks as follows

```
int foo(a, b) 
int a;
char b;
{ ...
```

It specifies the number of parameters, but still does not specify their types. Moreover, even though the number of parameters appears to be exposed by this declaration, it still formally declares `foo` the same way as `int foo();` does, meaning that calling it as `foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` still does not constitute a constraint violation.

The new style, i.e. declaration with prototype is better for obvious reasons: it exposes both the number and the types of parameters. It forces the compiler to check the validity of the call (with regard to the number and the types of parameters). And it allows the compiler to perform implicit type conversions from argument types to parameter types.

There are other, less obvious benefits provided by prototype declarations. Since the number and types of function parameters are known precisely to both the caller and the function itself, it is possible to choose the most efficient method of passing the arguments (the calling convention) at the point of the call without seeing the function definition. Without that information K&R implementations were forced to follow a single pre-determined "one size fits all" calling convention for all functions.